# How to delete record from a table without deleting the referenced user in Spring Boot JPA?"

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, jpa

I have a table of users and contacts, A user has many contacts and a contact has only one user.
When I try to delete a contact which references the user, the user is also being deleted.

Here is the code for the user model:

```
 @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Contact> contacts;

    public void addContact(Contact contact){
        contacts.add(contact);
    }
    public void removeContact(Contact contact){
        contacts.remove(contact);
    }
```

And the contact model:

```
@JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User user;
```

I have tried putting orphanRemoval = false after CascadeType.ALL to the contact table but it does not recognise it, I think that would solve the issue but its only being recognised on the User Side.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-delete -

Comment: If you don't want the user deleted, CascadeType.ALL is not what you want to be using. All includes CascadeType.Delete - so you are cascading the delete call on contact to the referenced User. Remove that and you should be good.

Comment: @Chris, thank you this fixed the issue of removing the CascadeType.ALL.